# Is islam.com part of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is [islam.com](http://islam.com) part of Stack Exchange, or is it only a copy-paste website? It's design is totally the same as SO's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not part of the network. If it would be, this would have been clearly indicated on the site itself, particularly in the footer.

We have our own Islam beta site: https://islam.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is an excact copy of the design but no it's not part of the Stack Exchange network. You can see all sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).